# Regarding Json load and dump

Tags: python

I am trying to substitute a value using safe substitute. Before this, I am converting an array using JSON dumps and then substituting. Once the substitution is done I am doing JSON loads and passing as a parameter to other utility. While doing this I am getting an error for JSON loads. Below is the code...

```
account_id={'ABC123', user_id='testing'}
var1 = {'account':account_id, 'user':user_id}
response = json.dumps(var1)
payload = Template.(test_template).safe_substitute(var1=var1)
output = json.loads(payload)
```

get an error when it comes to loads:

> Expecting "," delimiter: line 1 column 448 (char 447)

Comment: The JSON data is invalid, your substitution does not work as expected. Check the given character for the problem. In general edit the data, not the dumped JSON.

Comment: `{'ABC123', user_id='testing'}` this is not valid, as the value `'ABC123'` doesn't have a key

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a syntax error. Try, like below

```
account_id='ABC123'
user_id='testing'
var1 = {'account':account_id, 'user':user_id}
response = json.dumps(var1)
print(response)
# out: '{"account": "ABC123", "user": "testing"}'
output = json.loads(response)
print(output)
# out: {'user': 'testing', 'account': 'ABC123'}
```